# TensorFlow does not recognize my GPU

Tags: nvidia, gpu, 23.10, tensorflow

I did all the installation steps and when I try to use the GPU I see this message.

Ubuntu: 23.10

```
2024-03-24 20:22:51.323957: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] 
This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, 
rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```